# How to get Riak 2.0 security working with riak-python-client?

Tags: python, security, ssl-certificate, riak

Riak 2.0 is installed on Ubuntu 14.04 with default settings

Riak python client is taken from dev branch: https://github.com/basho/riak-python-client/tree/feature/bch/security

**Steps I made:**

1.Enable security:

```
> riak-admin security enable
```

2.Check status:

```
> riak-admin security status
> Enabled
```

3.Add example user, group and apply some basic permissions

4.Overall it looks like following:

**user:**

```
riak-admin security print-users

+----------+---------------+----------------------------------------+------------------------------+
| username |   member of   |                password                |           options            |
+----------+---------------+----------------------------------------+------------------------------+
| user_sec |   group_sec   |ce055fe0a2d621a650c293a56996ee504054ea1d|              []              |
+----------+---------------+----------------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

**user's grants:**

```
riak-admin security print-grants user_sec
Inherited permissions (user/user_sec)

+--------------------+----------+----------+----------------------------------------+
|       group        |   type   |  bucket  |                 grants                 |
+--------------------+----------+----------+----------------------------------------+
|     group_sec      | default  |    *     |              riak_kv.get               |
|     group_sec      |bucket_sec|    *     |              riak_kv.get               |
+--------------------+----------+----------+----------------------------------------+

Cumulative permissions (user/user_sec)

+----------+----------+----------------------------------------+
|   type   |  bucket  |                 grants                 |
+----------+----------+----------------------------------------+
| default  |    *     |              riak_kv.get               |
|bucket_sec|    *     |              riak_kv.get               |
+----------+----------+----------------------------------------+
```

**auth sources:**

```
riak-admin security print-sources

+--------------------+------------+----------+----------+
|       users        |    cidr    |  source  | options  |
+--------------------+------------+----------+----------+
|      user_sec      | 0.0.0.0/32 | password |    []    |
|      user_sec      |127.0.0.1/32|  trust   |    []    |
+--------------------+------------+----------+----------+
```

**simple python script I'm trying to run (on the same host where Riak is running):**

```
import riak
from riak.security import SecurityCreds
pbc_port = 8002
riak_host = "127.0.0.1"
creds = riak.security.SecurityCreds('user_sec', 'secure_password')
riak_client = riak.RiakClient(pb_port=pbc_port, host=riak_host, protocol='pbc', security_creds=creds)
bucket = riak_client.bucket('test')
data = bucket.get("42")
print data.data
```

stack trace I'm getting:
python riak_test.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "riak_test.py", line 8, in <module>
    data = bucket.get("42")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/riak/bucket.py", line 214, in get
    return obj.reload(r=r, pr=pr, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/riak/riak_object.py", line 307, in reload
    self.client.get(self, r=r, pr=pr, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/riak/client/transport.py", line 184, in wrapper
    return self._with_retries(pool, thunk)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/riak/client/transport.py", line 126, in _with_retries
    return fn(transport)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/riak/client/transport.py", line 182, in thunk
    return fn(self, transport, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/riak/client/operations.py", line 382, in get
    return transport.get(robj, r=r, pr=pr, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/riak/transports/pbc/transport.py", line 148, in get
    if self.quorum_controls() and pr:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/riak/transports/feature_detect.py", line 102, in quorum_controls
    return self.server_version >= versions[1]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/riak/util.py", line 148, in __get__
    value = self.fget(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/riak/transports/feature_detect.py", line 189, in server_version
    return LooseVersion(self._server_version())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/riak/transports/pbc/transport.py", line 101, in _server_version
    return self.get_server_info()['server_version']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/riak/transports/pbc/transport.py", line 119, in get_server_info
    expect=MSG_CODE_GET_SERVER_INFO_RESP)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/riak/transports/pbc/connection.py", line 51, in _request
    return self._recv_msg(expect)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/riak/transports/pbc/connection.py", line 137, in _recv_msg
    raise RiakError(err.errmsg)
riak.RiakError: 'Security is enabled, please STARTTLS first'
```

When security is disabled the same script works perfectly fine:

```
python riak_test.py
{u'question': u"what's the sense of universe?"}
```

I also tried to generate example certificates using this tool: https://github.com/basho-labs/riak-ruby-ca and set them in riak.conf:

```
grep ssl /etc/riak/riak.conf
## with the ssl config variable, for example:
ssl.certfile = $(platform_etc_dir)/server.crt
## Default key location for https can be overridden with the ssl
ssl.keyfile = $(platform_etc_dir)/server.key
## with the ssl config variable, for example:
ssl.cacertfile = $(platform_etc_dir)/ca.crt
```

and use ca.crt in python script:

```
creds = riak.security.SecurityCreds('user_sec', 'secure_password', 'ca.crt')
```

It didn't change anything. I'm still getting the same exception. I guess this problem might be trivial, but I don't have any clue for now.

**Update:**

I was using wrong param name. Few commits ago it was: **security_creds**, now it's called: **credentials**. 
When I fixed this in my script, SSL handshake was initialized. Then next exceptions were caused by wrong SecurityCreds initialization. Constructor is using named params, so it should be:

```
creds = riak.security.SecurityCreds(username='user_sec', password='secure_password', cacert_file='ca.crt')
```

handshake is initialized, but it's failing on this command:

```
ssl_socket.do_handshake()
```

from riak/transport/pbc/connection.py (line 134)

I'm getting these 2 errors (randomly):

```
    File "/home/gta/riak-python-client/riak/transports/pbc/connection.py", line 77, in _init_security
    self._ssl_handshake()
  File "/home/gta/riak-python-client/riak/transports/pbc/connection.py", line 145, in _ssl_handshake
    raise e
OpenSSL.SSL.SysCallError: (104, 'ECONNRESET')


    File "/home/gta/riak-python-client/riak/transports/pbc/connection.py", line 77, in _init_security
    self._ssl_handshake()
  File "/home/gta/riak-python-client/riak/transports/pbc/connection.py", line 145, in _ssl_handshake
    raise e
OpenSSL.SSL.SysCallError: (-1, 'Unexpected EOF')
```

I'm also observing errors in Riak's logs (/var/log/riak/error.log):

```
2014-06-02 15:09:33.954 [error] <0.1995.1> gen_fsm <0.1995.1> in state wait_for_tls terminated with reason: {error,{startls_failed,{certfile,badarg}}}
2014-06-02 15:09:33.955 [error] <0.1995.1> CRASH REPORT Process <0.1995.1> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: {error,{startls_failed,{certfile,badarg}}} in gen_fsm:terminate/7 line 622
2014-06-02 15:09:33.955 [error] <0.28750.0> Supervisor riak_api_pb_sup had child undefined started with {riak_api_pb_server,start_link,undefined} at <0.1995.1> exit with reason {error,{startls_failed,{certfile,badarg}}} in context child_terminated
```

This situation happens with both approaches: cacert (ca.crt) and client cert (client.crt)/key (client.key). I tried various combinations of keys:

- keys from tests/resource
- keys generated with riak-ruby-ca script
- keys generated with `make` in tests/resource
- keys generated with helper script from pyOpenSSL
- ...none of them work for me

I'm using **riak_2.0.0beta1-1_amd64.deb**

Comment: does the python client support TLS for protocol buffers? If you use `protocol='https'` does it make any difference?

Comment: @Joe, https is not a valid value. Only 'pbc' and 'http' are supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working. Things I had to make:

1. upgrade Erlang to version 16 (build from source)
2. pull latest Riak's source
3. build Riak from source
4. read once again (and more carefully) this paragraph: http://docs.basho.com/riak/2.0.0beta1/ops/running/security-sources/#Certificate-based-Authentication
5. set users (keep in mind: if you want to use Brett's certificates for testing, then you probably will need to add user called 'certuser')
6. set certificates in riak.config (I used Brett's example certs from /tests/resources)

seems that security features are not fully supported in Beta1 build

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the enthusiastic testing!  The branch you pulled is an unreviewed work in progress and I've added some updates today.

I would try again with both the very latest 2.0.0 beta and the changes made to this branch.  There are some test certs in `riak/tests/resources` which would be useful to get started testing your configuration.

You'll need to name your **cacert** parameter, now, too since several other options have been added.

The basic setup looks pretty good.  Try the latest and let me know how it works for you.

Comment: Hi Brett, could you take a look into updated section of my question? I included some new information about issues I'm facing today.

Comment: @przmk A couple of things:  That binary was built against 12.04LTS IIRC, so your mileage my vary.  Also, things have changed since Beta 1, like the need to add entries to `advanced.config` has since been removed.  Which version of OpenSSL to you have?  If you are running 14.04LTS, I suspect you are up-to-date, but make sure you have updated your distro.  Are you able or interested in building your own Riak Beta?

Comment: Good news! Looks like we now have a Trusty Tahr Beta 5 Release! http://s3.amazonaws.com/builds.basho.com/riak/develop/2.0.0beta5/ubuntu/trusty/riak_2.0.0beta5-1_amd64.deb

Comment: initially I messed something with OpenSSL & pyOpenSSL. My SSL.py was missing few things required by the client. It started working when I manually re-installed both: OpenSSL & pyOpenSSL.

Comment: Glad you finally got it working, @przmk! Feel free to user the riak-user mailing list, too, if you have further questions: http://lists.basho.com/mailman/listinfo/riak-users_lists.basho.com